# Pole Order of Weierstrass Coordinates

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to understand a proof in Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Background: For an elliptic curve $E$, $x, y \in K(E)$ such that $\phi = [x, y, 1]: E \rightarrow C$ is a basepoint preserving isomorphism with a curve $C$ given by a Weierstrass equation are called Weierstrass coordinates. (By 'basepoint preserving' I mean that $\phi(O) = (0 : 1: 0)$, where $O$ is the basepoint of $E$. Put differently $\phi$ is an Isogeny if $C$ itself is viewed as an elliptic curve.)

In Silverman's proof about the relation between two pairs of Weierstrass coordinates (see *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Ch. III Proposition 3.1) it is claimed that all Weierstraß coordinates $x, y$ have poles at the basepoint of orders 2 and 3, respectively.
I know that, since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, I can check this for the rational functions $X/Z$ and $Y/Z$ on $C$ instead. As $C$ is nonsingular, the line $Y = 0$ has 3 distinct intersections with C on the affine plane $Z \neq 0$, so $Y/Z$ has indeed order $-3$ at $(0 : 1 : 0)$.
But how can I proof that $X/Z$ has order $-2$ at the base point?

A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289859/proving-the-condition-for-two-elliptic-curves-given-in-weierstrass-form-to-be-is), but without a satisfactory answer (for me).

Comment: Does this help? http://math.stackexchange.com/a/512825/14699

Comment: This actually helped, thanks!

Comment: OK, so I'm still struggling with $char K = 2$. In that case, the Weierstrass equation doesn't look as nice, in particular, I don't know whether $Y + a_1 X + a_3 Z$ vanishes at $(e_i : 0 : 1)$. (Is it even true for $char K = 2$ that the cubic on the right has non-zero discriminant?)

Comment: Characteristic 2 is messy as always, and my link does not apply. One would have to deal with it using a model that is smooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I solved it now. For future reference, I'll post it here.

> Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with basepoint $O$, defined over a field $k$. Let $x, y \in k(E)$ be Weierstrass coordinates, i.e. rational functions such that
>   $$\phi = [x, y, 1] : E \rightarrow C$$
>   is an isomorphism with a curve $C$ given by a Weierstrass equation and $\phi(O) = (0 : 1 : 0)$.
>   Then 
>   \begin{equation*}
>     \operatorname{ord}_O x = -2 \\
>     \operatorname{ord}_O y = -3.
> \end{equation*}

*Proof.* Instead of calculating the poler orders of $x$ and $y$, we can check the pole orders of $X/Z = {\phi^*}^{-1}(x)$, $Y/Z = {\phi^*}^{-1}(y)$ in $(0 : 1 : 0)$ because $\phi$ is an isomorphism.
Notice that $(0 : 1 : 0)$ is in the affine open set $Y \neq 0$, so we dehomogenize the Weierstrass equation for $Y$ and get
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
Z + a_1 X Z + a_3 Z^2 = X^3 + a_2 X^2 Z + a_4 X Z^2 + a_6 Z^3.
\end{equation}
We're interested in the zero orders of $X$ and $Z$ in $(0, 0)$, which is the basepoint $(0 : 1 : 0)$ in affine coordinates.
The ideal of functions $M_{(0, 0)} \subset K[X, Z]$ that vanish in $(0, 0)$ is generated by $X$ and $Z$.
Solving (1) for $Z$ yields
\begin{equation*}
\tag{2}
Z = X^3 + a_2 X^2 Z + a_4 X Z^2 + a_6 Z^3 - a_1 X Z + a_3 Z^2,
\end{equation*}
so the zero order of $Z$ mod Weierstrass equation has to be at least $2$ because every summand on the right hand side is the product of at least 2 elements of $M_{(0, 0)}$. But then even $\operatorname{ord}_{(0, 0)} Z \geq 3$, since all summands have at least order 3.
As $C$ is non-singular, one of $X$ or $Z$ has to be a uniformizing parameter of order 1, so $\operatorname{ord}_{(0, 0)} X = 1$. Thus, the order of $Z$ is exactly 3 for otherwise, solving (2) for $X$ would imply $\operatorname{ord}_{(0, 0)} X^3 \gt 3$.
From the  properties of valuations, it is immediate that
\begin{equation*}
\tag{3}
\operatorname{ord}_{(0, 0)} X / Z = -2, \\
\operatorname{ord}_{(0, 0)} 1 / Z = -3,
\end{equation*}
but these are just the functions $X/Z$, $Y/Z \in K(C)$ in affine coordinates.